# Site prints all PHP instead of using it

Tags: php, html

another problem. I'm making a CMS and I want the login link to disapear when I want to. So   I can configure it in my adminCP. When I "flip the switch" my configfunctions.php changes `$login` to true.

To use it I'm doing:

`<?php if($loginenabled = true) { '<li><a href="sample-login.html" class="login"><span class="mmLogin">Login</span></a></li>' }; ?>`

but my site literally prints ALL PHP, also when I do other PHP. So my site looks like:

`Home, About us, <?php if($loginenabled = true) { 'login' }; ?>`

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Wesley

Comment: Is the filename you are editing `something.html`? If so that's why it's _not_ processed as php.

Comment: Unrelated, but if($loginenabled = true) will always return true since you're using the assignment operator '=' and not a '==' or '===' operator.

Comment: ^...Because it'll set the variable to true, not compare it. I'm not sure why PHP allows this operator in this context.

Comment: AD7six, No, ofcourse not. Just a .php file.

Comment: Then, of course, your server is misconfigured or the code you've put in the question isn't representative of what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't output HTML code by simply creating a string. To write output, you can use the [`echo`](http://php.net/echo) statement:

```
<?php if ($loginEnabled == true) {
    echo '<li><a href="sample-login.html" class="login"><span class="mmLogin">Login</span></a></li>';
}; ?>
```

Note the semicolon at the end of the single quotes (`'`). You can also use PHP's [alternate syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for control structures for cleaner code:

```
<?php if ($loginEnabled == true): ?>
    <li><a href="sample-login.html" class="login">
        <span class="mmLogin">Login</span>
    </a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The above will accomplish the same thing. Also note that `($loginEnabled = true)` is always true, since `=` is an assignment operator. To check if `$loginEnabled` is true, use:

```
if ($loginEnabled == true)
```

You can also shorten it to simply:

```
if ($loginEnabled)
```

Read more on [assignment operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php), [comparison operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), and the [`if` statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php).

Comment: Okay, thanks for this, but it still doesn't answer my question. Why does my page print all code instead of running it. I used your method -> still doing it....